# Why addDays not working?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This piece of code tries to set 4 labels as week x, week x+1, week x+2 and week x+3, but failed when updating with addDays(7), I only get week x, week x, week x and week x. Anyone can see the error?

```
 ui->setupUi(this);
QDate fecha=QDate::currentDate();
int pr=fecha.weekNumber();
int year=fecha.year();
ui->lab1->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr) + "\n" + " Year " +QString::number(year));
ui->lab5->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr) + "\n" + "Year " +QString::number(year));
fecha.addDays(7);
pr=fecha.weekNumber();
year=fecha.year();
ui->lab2->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr) + "\n" + "Year " +QString::number(year));
ui->lab6->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr) + "\n" + "Year " +QString::number(year));
fecha.addDays(7);
pr=fecha.weekNumber();
year=fecha.year();
ui->lab3->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr) + "\n" + "Year " +QString::number(year));
ui->lab7->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr)  + "\n" + "Year " +QString::number(year));
fecha.addDays(7);
pr=fecha.weekNumber();
year=fecha.year();
ui->lab4->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr) + "\n" + "Year " +QString::number(year));
ui->lab8->setText("Week "+ QString::number(pr) + "\n" + "Year " +QString::number(year));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`addDays()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#addDays) function returns an object with the modification of times, that is, it does not accumulate in the initial object.

> **QDate QDate::addDays(qint64 ndays) const**
>
> Returns a QDate object containing a date ndays later than the date of
>   this object (or earlier if ndays is negative).
>
> Returns a null date if the current date is invalid or the new date is
>   out of range.

You must reassign what returns to the variable:

```
fecha = fecha.addDays(7);
```